# Using sed to extract HTML data

Tags: linux, sed, awk

If I have a line of HTML

```
<td><em>data</em></td>
```

How can I print to stdout

```
<em>data</em>
```

if the beginning and end of the line have exactly

```
<td>
```

and

```
</td>
```

tags exactly.  If the line does not start or end with td tags, do not print the line.

I tried

```
sed 's/<td>\(*\)</td>/\1/'
```

but it doesn't exactly work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added information in my post what is wrong with your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
echo "<td><em>data</em></td>" | awk '{gsub(/<\/?td>/,x)}8'
<em>data</em>
```

Or this:

```
echo "<td><em>data</em></td>" | sed 's|</*td>||g'
<em>data</em>
```

Or this: (more exact, since `?` represent only a single character)

```
echo "<td><em>data</em></td>" | sed 's|</\?td>||g'
<em>data</em>
```

---

To go through what is wrong with your work `sed 's/<td>\(*\)</td>/\1/'`
You are nearly there, but this `\(*\)` does not work, since it does not now what to repeat `*`
Adding a simple `.` make this works, since it represent any characters. So it should be `\(.*\)`
In the second `td` there is a forward slash `/`. Since you are using `/` as separator int must be
escaped like this `/\` giving `<\/td>` so this is working:

```
echo "<td><em>data</em></td>" | sed 's/<td>\(.*\)<\/td>/\1/g'
<em>data</em>
```

It could be change to:

```
echo "<td><em>data</em></td>" | sed 's|<td>\(.*\)</td>|\1|g'
<em>data</em>
```

But as you see in my example above, there are no need to use back reference. It better to just
remove what you do not need.

---

If this `if the beginning and end of the line have exactly` mean start/end of line has nothing more.
back reference:

```
sed 's|^<td>\(.*\)</td>$|\1|g'
```

just delete:

```
sed 's:^<td>\|</td>$::g'
```

and `awk`:

```
echo "<td><em>data</em></td>" | awk '{gsub(/^<td>|<\/td>$/,x)}8'
<em>data</em>
```

Comment: OP mentions *beginning of line* and *start or end with*. Maybe add some anchorings for completeness `^$`

Comment: It would then be `sed 's|^<td>\(.*\)</td>$|\1|g'` or just remove `sed 's|^<td>||g;s|<\/td>$||g'`

Comment: You can delete with a single expression: `sed 's:^<td>\|</td>$::g'`

Comment: @grebneke Thanks, did use that in my `awk` but did forget `sed` updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's:<td>(.*)<\/td>:\1:g' <<< '<td><em>data</em></td>'
<em>data</em>
```

If your requirement is as simple as you have mentioned in your question, then `sed` is fine to use. However, if you want to parse HTML tags, then consider using [`perl`](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%7BPAN%20%2b%20HTML%20PArser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#q=perl%20HTML%20tags%20parser&spell=1) as `sed` would be way to efficient in doing so. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Do you accept `awk`?

```
cat INFILE.txt | awk '/<td>/ { found=1; next }; /<\/td>/ { found=0; next }; found {print}'
```

- where **INFILE.txt** is the input file
- This command will print between `<td>` and `</td>` even if the tags span multiple lines ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '\|^[[:blank:]]*<[tT][dD]>\(.*\)</[tT][dD]>[[:blank:]]*$| s//\1/p' YourFile
```

take only lines starting/closing with this td tag (with any space surrounding) a print the content
(-posix with GNU sed)